What is the meaning and common use of "ad libitum" ("ad lib.")?
In Latin, "libita" means "will, pleasure", hence "ad libitum" means "at your will / as you please".  When preceded by another word, it becomes clear what exactly should be done at the performer's will, as in cadenza ad libitum (improvise any cadence you like), or, as this site suggests, pedale ad libitum (use the damper pedal as you see fit).
Now, in music there are many words related to tempo (ritardando, accelerando, a tempo, tempo I and a host of others).  So tempo ad libitum could be a valid marking; however, is it actually used?  (I mean, I'm positive I've seen it, it's just that I no longer trust my memory.)
Regarding its meaning, I've seen three distinct interpretations in various sources:

choose any tempo (and play in that tempo);
play in tempo but speed up and slow down, like rubato (which itself seems to be a vague term);
play without a tempo, choosing note durations irrespectively of their written values.

Which of the meanings is correct / common / most often used?
Lastly, and what bothers me most, are there cases when ad libitum occurs as a direction by itself, without any qualifier?  If so, what does it mean?  Should one infer its meaning from the context, like when it is written beside a part, "play or omit this part at will"?
I will greatly appreciate if you mention examples from published music.  I seem to recall seeing ad lib. here and there but just now I've looked through some piano music including many Chopin pieces and a couple of piano concertos and haven't been able to spot any.  Could it be that ad lib. is not used that often?

"ad lib" isn't very common in my experience, but it's not unusual, either.  I vaguely recall having seen it by itself, but I am fairly confident that it was clear from the context exactly what was being left to the performer's pleasure.

Some music dictionaries I have seen specify ad lib (on its own) means at liberty "with regard to speed". The wikipedia entry https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_libitum gives other meanings.

@Peter yes, definitely "solo ad libitum" can mean improvised solo. I would think you can write " ad libitum".

Ad lib - 'at will'. Several meanings.

To vary from the strict rhythm, tempo, if inclined.

To include, or omit, some part or voice or instrument marked ad lib.

To include, or omit, some passage marked ad lib, like a cadenza, if the player wants.

To make ones own cadenza at the marked place, in other words, extemporise.


Any or all will be at the player's discretion, according to mood at the time, or context, which will be fair and square down to the player (or the conductor).
So 'carte blanche' could be another term used. Obviously in a strict tempo part, changing the tempo won't be such a good idea, with others playing, as will changing the harmonies when the rest are playing what's written!

ad libitum is usually used in two ways. One is that you may or may not include a part by your discretion (say a contrabassoon part), the other one is that phrasing, dynamics, agogics and tempo are up to the player’s discretion.
So ad libitum already includes the tempo and can mean any of the variants you’ve given.
In tempo markings this is not usual. More commonly you’ll find the Italian term con licenza, literally meaning with permission [to play it your own way]. You find this marking for example in Tchaikovsky’s 5th/II: Andante cantabile, con alcuna licenza.

Doesn't "con alcuna licenza" mean the opposite of "con licenza"?

@psmears - no. 'With some licence'.

@Tim: Interesting - Google Translate suggests "with no licence" but I see a proper dictionary says it can be "no" or "some" depending on context.

I imagine it's similar to negation in French, where "ne" carries the actual negative meaning but you're expected to conjugate it with a word like "pas", "aucun" etc. which strictly has a positive meaning but is a negative-polarity item.

@psmears alcuno means some, but in negations is means no/not any. The dictionary you quote gives this by non... alcuno, but also in other combinations with negating meaning, such as senza. Essentially not some equals no/not any. The google translate is incorrect. Interestingly google translates gives with no and with some for different nouns in con alcuno/a ....

@psmears But then testing against different translation services all but one (OpenL) get that translation wrong. I think this is due to use of machine learning where certain phrases are mostly used in a negated context, the model learns a combination alcuno/a X as no X.

@Lazy - so artificial intelligence isn't that intelligent after all. AI could stand for absolute idiocy in some cases!

@Tim Of course using machine translation for musical term is interesting in the first place. Google translate turns Andante con moto con licenza into riding with a licensed motorcycle ...

@KarlKnechtel As I understand it‘s roughly like French aucun as you say, but in Italian the shift from default meaning “some” to the implied negative “not any” is more recent and less complete. So Google Translate is correct for the modern colloquial meaning, but the musical usage preserves the older sense.
